# Tomcat Alpha SSL configuration

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, tomcat, https

I got CA file (PFX), root certificate and intermediate certificate from AlphaSSL. I just put PFX in a location and configured Connector in tomcat server.XML with keystoreFile, keystorePass, keystoreType (as PKC12).

It works fine in desktop browser (except one instance of Firefox) and it doesn't work in Android chrome browser. Interestingly, it works in Opera Mini Android browser.

I tried my level best to configuring root and intermediate certificates by following several steps found in Google but no luck.

Kindly help.

Comment: What does `https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/` say about your site? I suspect there is a mismatch between what your site supports (possibly only very strong encryption, e.g. TLS 1.2 with only a few ciphers) and what your browsers support (in their various configurations).

Answer (score 0):

Running your site through SSL Labs's SSL test, I can see that your certificate chain is incomplete. The certificate for "AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2" is not being sent by the server along with you server's certificate. Import that certificate to your keystore the restart your Tomcat instance. This should clear-up some of your errors.

Your site does not support SSLv3 (which is generally a good thing). If you have clients that absolutely require SSLv3, then you will have to re-enable it. I don't know what version of Android Chrome you are running, but if it's old enough, it might require SSLv3. If it does, upgrade that device or throw it away: it's worthless in its current state. Your can test your client by visiting [Qualys's Client Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html) from that device to see its capabilities.

Your site has a few ciphers configured (non-elliptic-curve DHE) which are weak, and do not properly-protect your clients. You should disable those ciphers, or, better yet, upgrade your version of Java running underneath Tomcat: some (all?) of those ciphers have been disabled in recent versions of Java.

Other than that, things look good. I think this is more likely to be a client issue than a server one.

Comment: I completed certificate chain. It works with mobile browser as well. But somehow I couldn't get A rating for DH key. How to setup this in Java 8 and Tomcat 9?

Comment: If you have a different questions, ask it separately from this one. Is your server working with all clients, now?